# keep all distinct columns, instead of one r

Tags: r, filter, dplyr, distinct

I'm attempting to find all senders who have sent to 4 or more separate receivers (by name), where the total amount sent to those separate receivers exceeds $5000.00 and looking for a way to tell r to maintain all values containing the distinct names, instead of just one.

For instance, using the following data.frame:

```
sender<-c("tom","tom","kevin","frank","tom","chris","tom","tom","craig","louis",
      "john", "tom","brian","tom","George")
reciever<-c("ryan","dave","sarah","kel","eric","ben","wayne","mike","brenda","christina",
        "brianna","hal","sam","ryan","van")
amount<-as.numeric(c("200","100","300","3000","100","350","100","90","670","865","600",
      "300","1300","5200","200"))
dF<-data.frame(sender,reciever,amount)
```

Applying the following parameters using dpylr:

```
dF1<-dF%>%
  distinct(reciever,.keep_all = TRUE)%>%
  group_by(sender)%>%
  summarise(
    count=n(),
    total = sum(amount)  
  )%>%
  filter(count >= 4 & total>5000)
```

You will notice that the target in the example sender vector is tom. tom has 2 transactions with Ryan, however, due to the nature of the distinct function, r pulls the first column with ryan where the corresponding amount is 200, and excludes the other column with ryan, which is 5200. This exclusion presents an issue, as the excluded transaction (if included) would meet the logic of the $5000 threshold applied in the filter.

Is there a way, using the distinct function, to tell r to keep all of the occurrences involving a similar distinct name? Or, should I approach this from a completely different angle?

Thank you!

Comment: As a follow-up, if there is a better way to do this with SQL, feel free to provide your proposed SQL code, as I can load the sqldf package into r. Thank you for taking a look!

Comment: It would be better if you also show the expected output for crosschecking

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We could use

```
library(dplyr)
dF %>%
    group_by(sender) %>% 
    filter(n_distinct(reciever) >=4, sum(amount) >=5000) %>%
    ungroup
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 7 x 3
  sender reciever amount
  <chr>  <chr>     <dbl>
1 tom    ryan        200
2 tom    dave        100
3 tom    eric        100
4 tom    wayne       100
5 tom    mike         90
6 tom    hal         300
7 tom    ryan       5200
```

---

If we need only those pairs that meet the condition

```
dF %>%
     group_by(sender) %>% 
     filter(n_distinct(reciever) >=4, sum(amount) >=5000) %>%
     group_by(sender, reciever) %>% filter(sum(amount) >= 5000)
# A tibble: 2 x 3
# Groups:   sender, reciever [1]
#  sender reciever amount
#  <chr>  <chr>     <dbl>
#1 tom    ryan        200
#2 tom    ryan       5200
```